# What language is the C# .NET 4.5 TcpClient class implemented in?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I was wondering if anyone knows what language was used for the implementation. I looked at the msdn documentation to see if I could look at the implementation but I didn't see any there. I would like to know how it works at the lower levels.

Comment: Win32 levels generally speaking.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,e7dfc77c8d4c574f

Comment: Thanks for that link, it's amazing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implemented in C#. The reference source is public.

Eventually, the .NET code uses PInvoke to call native Win32 APIs. The `Socket` API also uses some native CLR hooks. For example, in the `Overlapped` system. That seems to be a pure performance optimization to me.

Basically, you could implement `TcpClient` yourself. Nothing magic about it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the informative bits about Win32 APIs and CLR hooks. I'll look into it.